# JQuery best practice: run effects between elements in sequence

Tags: jquery

is there a better way than this? Kindly let me learn from you. TIA

```
$('ul').children(':first-child').delay('fast').fadeToggle('fast', function () {
    $(this).delay().fadeToggle(function () {
        $(this).next().delay().fadeToggle(function () {
            $(this).delay().fadeToggle(function () {
                $(this).next().delay().fadeToggle(function () {
                    $(this).delay().fadeToggle(function () {
                        $(this).closest('#welcome').next().toggle();
                        $(this).closest('#welcome').slideToggle(function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                            $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rKVkd/

Comment: Have you tried using .each() and then iterate through each animation by incrementing the delay.

Comment: @Stefan Dunn, thanks I'll try that and report back here ..

Comment: Simply use `.delay(i*100)` (where `i` is a cursor) to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you can apply flash_show to any list to accomplish the same effect. And a general callback will get called when the show is finished.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rKVkd/1/)

```
function flash_show(cb) {
    var $e = $(this).next();

    $(this).fadeToggle().delay().fadeToggle('fast', function () {
        $e.size() == 0 ? cb.call(this) : flash_show.call($e, cb);    
    })
}

flash_show.call($('ul li')[0], function () {
    $(this).closest('#welcome').next().toggle();
    $(this).closest('#welcome').slideToggle(function () {
        $(this).remove();
        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    });
})
```

Comment: awesome. Learn much from you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#welcome, #content').height($(window).height());

function toggleUl($ul, complete) {
    var $li = $ul.find('.current').removeClass('current').next();
    if (!$li.length) {
        $li = $ul.children().first();
    }
    $li.addClass('current')
    $li.fadeIn('fast', function () {
        $(this).delay(250).fadeOut('fast', function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.is(':last-child')) {
                complete();
            } else {
                toggleUl($ul, complete);
            }
        })
    });
}

toggleUl($('ul'), function () {
    $('#welcome').next().toggle();
    $('#welcome').slideToggle(function () {
        $(this).remove();
        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Beu9G/)